# Swift Map request on different generations

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary

When it comes to iPhone devices, and using the map iPhone four can not handle

```
 manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

But anything post iPhone4 requires that. How can I make it so the software will run successfully on both device types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
   func triggerLocationServices() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        if     self.manager.respondsToSelector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization") { 
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } else {
        startUpdatingLocation()
    }
   }
 }

  func startUpdatingLocation() {
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()
 }

   // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || status == .Authorized {
    startUpdatingLocation()
}
  }
```